# CollectionView in TableViewCell scroll isn't smooth in swift3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uitableview, collectionview

[image: Here is my CollectionView in TableViewCell]

In my project `CollectionView` in `TableViewCell` isn't display and I added

```
cell.collectionView.reloadData()
```

in my code. After I added, `CollectionView` displayed in `TableViewCell`, but 
`ScrollView` isn't smooth. How to solve this problem. If someone have any experience or ideas help me. Thanks.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homecell") as! HomeCategoryRowCell

    let mainThemeList = mainHomeThemeTable[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.categoryTitle.text = mainThemeList.main_name
        cell.collectionView.reloadData()
    }


    return cell
}
```

CollectionView in my project,

```
extension HomeCategoryRowCell : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        debugPrint("assetsTable count \(assetsTable.count)")
        return assetsTable.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeVideoCell

        let list = assetsTable[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        let url2 = NSURL(string:list.poster_image_url)
        let data2 = NSData(contentsOf:url2! as URL)
        //  debugPrint(list.poster_image_url)
        DispatchQueue.main.async(){
            cell.movieTitle.text = list.name
            cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data2! as Data)

        }

        return cell

    }

}
```

Comment: just give delegate and datasource of collectioview  in tableview's cellforrow method dont reload colletioview

Comment: collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        
I already added. But not solved the problem @JeckyModi

Comment: What are you loading in collectionview? If images then Please make sure that images are not of high resolution.

Comment: Why are you using `DispatchQueue.main.async`? You don't seem to be on a different thread. Have you tried without?

Comment: DispatchQeue.main.async for cell.categoryTitle.text = mainThemeList.main_name. If I didn't use Dispcatch, background thread has a problem.@pesch

Comment: images are low resolution @JeckyModi

Comment: Can you share demo? Through only this much code how can I understand problem ? @SanSan

Comment: Remove this line cell.collectionView.reloadData()
you ned to call this line when your assigning array to collectionview

Comment: I remove this line cell.collectionView.reloadData() in my project, collectionView data didn't appear that's why I added this line. @AbhishekThapliyal

Comment: the place you have assign the array for collection view

Comment: add your complete code also so that i can show you

Comment: I added collectionView bro @AbhishekThapliyal Thanks!

Comment: Download Image Url Data in UICollectionView-itemForRow:  ASYNCHRONOUSLY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Image Url Data in `collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath` delegate  -  `ASYNCHRONOUSLY`

Create a Class

First cache the image Data with respect to key Image URL

Why do we need to cache the data?

Because - While scrolling we don't need to download Image Every Time so Cache the already downloaded Image Data and return the cache data

I created a class name: `AsyncImageLoader` then I created a function which is a completion handler which returns the data after completion of downloading Image

```
class AsyncImageLoader {

static let cache = NSCache<NSString, NSData>()

class func image(for url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping(_ image: UIImage?) -> ()) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background).async {

        if let data = self.cache.object(forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { completionHandler(UIImage(data: data as Data)) }
            return
        }

        guard let data = NSData(contentsOf: url) else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { completionHandler(nil) }
            return
        }

        self.cache.setObject(data, forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { completionHandler(UIImage(data: data as Data)) }
    }
}

}
```

How to use AsyncImageLoader Class?

See below How I used in  `collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let yourCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionCell

    yourCell.url = URL(string: "\(item_ImageUrl)")

   return yourCell
}
```

CustomCollectionCell

```
class CustomCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var cellImageDisplayView: UIImageView!

var url: URL? {
    didSet {
        if let url = url {

           cellImageDisplayView.image = nil

            AsyncImageLoader.image(for: url, completionHandler: { (image) in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    if let img = image {

                        self.cellImageDisplayView.image = img


                    }else{
                        let dummyImage = UIImage(named: "img_u")
                        self.cellImageDisplayView.image = dummyImage
                    }
                }

            })

        }else{

            let dummyImage = UIImage(named: "img_u")
            self.cellImageDisplayView.image = dummyImage

        }
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Wow! after I added your code , my project is now smooth. Thanks for the best answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

After I added above code , my project become more smooth. I'll try the best and back with the best solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are directly getting data from url and then image from data in main thread. You should use image downloading library to download the image from url
Here is the good third party to download image from url asynchronously.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Try with this I am 100% sure it will solve your problem.

Thanks