# CustomCell images change while scrolling in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**issue:** API calls again while scrolling table.
Code which I have done :

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    ITableViewCell* cell = ( ITableViewCell* )[self.tblNotes dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NoteTableCell"];

    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    if(cell.tag == indexPath.row) {
        cell = [cell initWithNote:[notesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];
    return cell;
}
```

I don't want to call `initWithNote` while scrolling.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why you use cell.tag please tell me? when you want to call initWithNote?

Comment: I use https://stackoverflow.com/a/32415336/3378413 reference there it mentioned to resolve this issue

Comment: While scrolling my tableview I don't want to call an api's again.

Comment: like a lazy loading

Comment: wait i give answer that you want to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   ITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NoteTableCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NoteTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    id object = [notesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)object;
        [cell.userNameforNotes setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dict valueForKey:@"uploadedBy"] uppercaseString]]];
        [cell.noteDescription setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dict valueForKey:@"description"] uppercaseString]]];
        [cell.dateForNotes setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dict valueForKey:@"uploadedDate"] uppercaseString]]];
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict valueForKey:@"incidentID"]];
        [cell.noteImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I am not using dictionary I am using nsarray

Comment: @MihirOza can you try now.

Comment: What you mean by loadNibNamed ?

Comment: you tableview cell if custom cell otherwise ignor that cell=nil code

Comment: code is not execute inside [object isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]] condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167310/discussion-between-realmoffire-and-mihir-oza).

Answer (score 0):

For that you can detect tableview is scrolling with the help of this delegate `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`, if it is then you can maintain some flag or something which can tell your code to not call `initWithNote:`. After scrolling will finish that you can check it with `scrollViewDidEndDragging:` you can do whatever you wants to do. As tableview contains scrollview so you can easily take the help from scrollview delegates.